# (very) old version of Postfix in Ubuntu Trusty

Tags: 14.04, server, apt, email, postfix

I'm active user (admin) of several Postfix-based mail stacks. Last year in December I've installed **Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr)** for the first time and set up Postfix with components, as usual.

One extremely strange thing I've noticed that offered version of Postfix is (currently) [2.11.0-1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/postfix). Um... that's version so old that it's release date cannot be found on [official announcements page](http://www.postfix.org/announcements.html) (it has versions up to 2008).

[Even more strange is the fact that older Ubuntu LTS - Precise - maintains decent version of Postfix (2.9.1-4).](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/postfix)

I would like to know is there known reason for this? And, more importantly, what should user of Ubuntu Trusty do? (PPAs?)

EDIT:
Xenial has super-up-to-date version of [Postfix (3.1.0-3)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/postfix). So, only Trusty is black sheep of the family.

Comment: Half-answer is that the version in a given release is explained by [this question about why the repos don't have the latest software versions](http://askubuntu.com/q/151283/10616).  Second half-answer is that you have to resort to back ports, PPAs, or building from source yourself to fix this type of issue (or upgrade to 16.04).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official announcement page says that 2.11.0 has been released on January 15, 2014.

2.9.1 is about 2 years older (released February 18, 2012).

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Thanks. Cant' believe what I've missed...